# jQuery select2 - Data attribute with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

With select2, can I set the attribute "data" on all `<option>` tag using select2 ajax method to take the values ​​of the `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = '<option value="test1" data-temp="test1_data">test1</option><option value="test2" data-temp="test2_data">test2</option>';

   $("#test").empty().append(options).select2();

        $("#test").on('change',function(){

        alert($(this).find(":selected").data('temp'));
   });
});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/falam/1/edit)